# Use imported dll inner class methods in c++

Tags: c++, dll, linker, java-native-interface, dllimport

I've got a problem using 3rd party .dll library: 
That library has some class with methods I need to use in my compiled .dll via JNI from my Java app.
I'm trying to declare something like that :

```
#ifdef SERVER_EXPORTS
#define SERVER_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define SERVER_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

namespace MYDLLNAMESPACE
{
class SERVER_API IServer
{
public:
     int NFun(int func);
};

class SERVER_API ServerClass : public IServer {
public:
    ServerClass();
    int NFun(int func) {
        return MYDLLNAMESPACE::ServerClass::NFun(func);
    }
};
}
```

Ant then use it in code like :

```
IServer *Myserv = new Server();
int a = Myserv->NFun(5007);
return a;
```

but it goes to the error **"error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall MYDLLNAMESPACE::IServer:"**

I need to do something like:

`Iserver myServer = new Server();
int result = myServer.do_smth();
return result;`

where **Server** is **MYDLL.dll --> namespace MYDLLNAMESPACE --> class Server**

Is there any ways how to do it?

P.S. I haven't any .lib of .h files of 3rd party .dll

**EDIT:**
Now I've got Server.h file :

```
namespace NS {
class __declspec(dllexport) ServerClass
{
public:
    ServerClass() {
    }
   const char* GParam(const char* key);
  const char* SParam(const char* key, const char* value);
};
}
```

And my Impl.cpp file, where I tryin' to instantiate ServerClass and use its method 'GParam' like this:

```
ServerClass *serv = new ServerClass();
const char* str = serv->GParam("LastErrorTxt");
```

but it goes to StackOverFlowException, seems like **serv->GParam("LastErrorTxt")** is executing itself instead of dll class implementation

Comment: You can't expect to export a class from your DLL. Flatten the interface.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do't want to export a class, I need just to use methods it provides. What do you mean by 'Flatten the interface'?

Comment: Your code exports a class. You aren't going to be able to call methods without first having an instance. Where are you going to get that instance from? Concept of flattening is explained here: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html#flattening

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, please correct me if I'm wrong with the following:
To get what I want, I need;
1) Add 3rd party .dll as a reference to c++ project
I got .dll with namespace NS, which contains IServer and ServerClass objects.
2) In header file a.h, declare namespace NS and interface for accessing ServerClass(because I dont need to implement its interface, just need a constructor and three methods)
3) Flatten that interface in a.cpp file 
4) Provide an handler for a.cpp file methods from 3 step in b.h file
5) Use interface I did in step 4 to create instance in my Impl.cpp file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by using com4j:
**http://com4j.kohsuke.org/**